# Creating arrays from Mysql queries inside a foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to populate a table displaying statistics. I have a list of campaign id's have been placed into an array using the following query:

```
$query = "SELECT `id` FROM `c_templates` ORDER BY `id`";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $id[] = $row['id'];
}
```

Once I have all of my id's, I am using a foreach loop to make 5 queries per id gathering all the table data.

```
foreach($id as $i){
    // sent
    $query = "SELECT `template`, COUNT(*) as count FROM `s_log` WHERE `template` = '".$i."' AND `time_sent` BETWEEN '".$start."' AND '".$stop."'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $template[] = $row['template'];
        $count[] = $row['count'];
    }

    // opens
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM `t_opens` WHERE `campaign_id` = '".$i."' AND `timestamp` BETWEEN '".$start."' AND '".$stop."'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $opens[] = $row['count'];
    }

    // clicks   
    $query = "SELECT `campaign_id`, COUNT(*) as count FROM `t_analytics` WHERE `campaign_id` = '".$i."' AND `timestamp` BETWEEN '".$start."' AND '".$stop."'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $click_count[] = $row['count'];
    }

    // conversions
    $query = "SELECT `conversion_value`, COUNT(*) as count FROM `t_analytics` WHERE `campaign_id` = '".$i."' AND `timestamp` BETWEEN '".$start."' AND '".$stop."' AND `conversion_value` > 0";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $conversion_value[] = $row['conversion_value'];
        $conversion_count[] = $row['count'];
    }

    // bounce rate
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS `ck` FROM `s_log` WHERE `time_sent` BETWEEN '".$start."' AND '".$stop."' AND `status` = 'hardbounce' OR `status` = 'softbounce' AND `template` = '".$i."'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $bounce_count[] = $row['ck'];
    }
}
```

The issue is that this process takes 4-5 seconds to perform over 40-50 `id` records. I placed some timers after each query to confirm the queries were performing correctly and they were. I ran OPTIMIZE and double checked to be sure everything was properly indexed. As far as I can tell, the issue is not in mysql.

The only thing I could find is that there is a .1-.5 second delay after each loop cycle. When trying to run 40-50 rows, this definitely begins to add up.

My question: Is there a better and faster way to fetch this data? Is there something else I should be checking to speed the process up?

The only solution I could think of was to run one query for each statistic (5 total queries) fetching the data for all `id` and placing them in a array for later display. I'm not sure how that could be done or if it's even possible. It seems to me I would have to run a separate query for each `id`, but I'm hoping I'm wrong.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Do those queries in the loop execute correctly??  They all (except for the last one) seem to be missing `GROUP BY`.  Furthermore, in all but the fourth query you do not need to include the `campaign_id` in selection; including a constant value should be quicker - and not require `GROUP BY` then.

Comment: yes and they're very fast (.0001xxxx seconds).

Comment: `campaign_id` is present so the query pulls records for only that campaign `id`

Comment: also, the queries are only fetching a count and/or single record, so there is nothing to `GROUP BY`